# How to add another button that directs users to Facebook on uiAlert?

Tags: ios

I need to add a button Facebook, Then the action should take user to Facebook, I'm just not sure how to do it from the code below?

```
-(IBAction)btContinueClick:(id)sender{

    if(Level == [list count]){

        UIAlertView *info = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Good" message:@"Go to facebook?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"Facebook"];
        [info show]; //// Change Game End Message
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to go to Facebook app, or open facebook in browser?

Comment: application, thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure you have added UIAlertViewDelegate in .h file**

```
-(IBAction)btContinueClick:(id)sender{
if(Level == [list count]){


    UIAlertView *info = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Good" message:@"Go to facebook?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"Facebook"];
    [info show]; //// Change Game End Message
    info.delegate=self;

}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if(buttonIndex==1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Facebook selected.");
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/<id>"]; // provide the app ID
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];


    }
}
```

Comment: Like this: @interface ViewController : UIViewController <iInfoDataSource, iInfoDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate> - ?

Comment: @interface PlayViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>

Comment: check your code forgot to put @"Facebook", nil]; but it worked thanks, need to tweak it a bit with my code though!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to the native app of Facebook in iOS.

Using delegate method of `alertView`

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

  if(buttonIndex == 1) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) { //USE FB NATIVE APP
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
    else { //IF THE DEVICE IS UNABLE TO OPEN IN NATIVE APP, USE BROWSER INSTEAD
        NSURL *browserURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"];  
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:browserURL];
    }
  }
}
```